# Conditional Combine Rasters and Track which Raster pixel used

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, conditional, combine

I have 6 rasters with pixel values ranging from 0 to 1. I want to extract the highest pixel values from each raster to create a new raster, but also have a way to show which raster the highest value came from.

For example, pixel N has a value of 0.1 in Rast1, 0.5 in Rast2, 0.4 in Rast3.
I would like to keep the value from Rast2 in the output raster and somehow keep track that this value came from Rast2 not Rast 1 or 3. Ultimately I would like to symbolize the raster by which original file it came from.

Is this possible?

Comment: Raster data can only store one value per cell. If you need to store multiple values for your analysis, consider a vector based approach. What is your ultimate objective? Why do you need to keep track of which raster has the highest value?

Comment: Make 2 rasters... one with a value that *identifies the raster that will* be used and one with the value used. Con should be able to do that but the statement will be quite long.

Comment: No need for Con, use highest position tool, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a number of workarounds one way you can do this is in a 3 step process.

1. Step 1. Use `cell statistics` tool in ArcGIS, to make a raster of
   maximum values from input `raster1, raster2 and raster3`.<- let  step1
   output = MaxValue
2. Step 2. Use Conditional calculation:  `Con((Raster1 > Raster2)&
   (Raster1 >Raster3),1,Con((Raster2>
   Raster1)&(Raster2>Raster3),2,Con((Raster3>Raster1)&(Raster3>Raster2),3,0)))`
   <- let step2 output = MaxRaster
3. Step 3. Use `Combine raster` tool to compine rasters MaxValue and
   MaxRaster.

That should give you the maximum values with the rasters they came from in another column. 1 = from raster1, 2 = from raster2, 3 = from raster3 and 0 if for some reason the values are equal. 
Note: This becomes a tedious solution if you have more than 3 rasters, if that is the case may be a python scripting solution with arcpy is better suited.

Answer (score 2):

1. Per the [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175850/2856), use the [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) tool to determine the maximum value of the rasters;
2. Rather than an unwieldy `Con` function, use the [Highest Position](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/highest-position.htm) tool to determine which raster had the maximum value.

Comment: +1.  This should be *the* answer, because Highest Position is designed to do precisely what the question asks for.